# if (isset($_POST) Faz alguma coisa, se não faz outra

Tags: php

Tou aqui com um pequeno problema que não deve ser nada de mais... 
Eu tenho um formulario onde tenho dois radios buttons, e dependendo da seleção de um deles, a query vai ser diferente. Se o valor do meu radio button = 1 ele insere na tabela ofertas_pro, se não insere numa outra tabela.

O meu codigo está assim:

```
if (isset($_POST['visib'])){ 
if ($_POST['visib'] == '0'){  

//PRIMEIRA CONSULTA
$sql = "INSERT INTO ofertas (titulo, descricao, valor, user_of, categ, prioridade, local)
VALUES ('$titulo', '$descricao', '$valor', '$login_session','$categ','$pro_user','$local')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$diferenca=$saldo-$pro_user;
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET saldo='$diferenca' WHERE id=$id");

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
echo "Sucesso: Atualizado corretamente!";
}else{
echo "Aviso: Não foi atualizado!";
}
} 


//SEGUNDA CONSULTA

$sql = "INSERT INTO ofertas_pro (titulo, descricao, valor, user_of, categ,     local)
VALUES ('$titulo', '$descricao', '$valor', '$login_session','$categ','$local')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$diferenca=$saldo-$pro_user;
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET saldo='$diferenca' WHERE id=$id");

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
echo "Sucesso: Atualizado corretamente!";
}else{
echo "Aviso: Não foi atualizado!";
}
}
```

Da forma que esta, quando o Radio btn = 1 ele insere numa só tabela, tudo bem... quando é =0 ele insere nas duas tabelas... 
Como posso resolver isto?

Comment: Resolvido. Não era nada de mais, mesmo. Abraço

Comment: Para alterar um post clique no botão `editar` logo abaixo do seu post, não é necessário criar uma resposta para efetuar correções.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como padrão o HTML passa o valor de um radio-button como `on` ou `null (vazio)`

Primeiramente você deve verificar qual dos dois foi selecionado;

```
$radio1 = $_POST['nomeDoRadioButton-1'];
$radio2 = $_POST['nomeDoRadioButton-2'];

if (isset($radio1) && $radio1 != null) { // Verifica se o foi selecionado e não é nulo
// Faça alguma coisa
}
else if (isset($radio2) && $radio2 != null) { // Verifica se o foi selecionado e não é nulo
// Faça outra coisa
}

// Ou você pode passar valor númerico para simplificar
if ($radio1 == 'on'):
$radio1 = 1;
else: 
$radio2 = 1;
endif;
```

Comment: Certo @Rafael Acioly Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_POST['visib'] == '1'){ //<---- Acrescentei o que faltava 
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO ofertas_pro (titulo, descricao, valor, user_of, categ,     local)
VALUES ('$titulo', '$descricao', '$valor', '$login_session','$categ','$local')";

if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}


$diferenca=$saldo-$pro_user;
$up = mysql_query("UPDATE login SET saldo='$diferenca' WHERE id=$id");

if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0){
echo "Sucesso: Atualizado corretamente!";
}else{
echo "Aviso: Não foi atualizado!";
}
} 
}//<---- Fechei o que faltava
```